# CentOS Network Interface Post-Up Script Not Executing

Tags: linux, networking, interface, vpn

I am running CentOS 7.2, and I'm struggling to get a simple script to execute on ifup of any interface.

My `/sbin/ifup-local` looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
 if [[ "$1" == "eth0" ]]
   then
     exec /vpnup
 fi
[root@oracle2 ~]#
```

The referenced script `/vpnup` looks like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# CompanyX Production L2TP VPN - UP
#
#
echo -e "\n"
echo -e "PLEASE WAIT\n"
echo -e "Dialling Production L2TP VPN... \n"
echo -e ".........................................\n"
ipsec auto --up L2TP-PSK && echo "c qvprodvpn" > /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control
echo -e ".........................................\n"
echo "Connected..."
echo "Adding local static route to manage VPN bound traffic..."
sleep 6s
ip route add 10.10.24.0/24 via 10.10.24.51
echo "Route added..."
echo -e "...\n"
```

Fairly simple, the script works fine when called at command line. It just dials into a L2TP VPN that I've setup, to get this box access to the production LAN of another segment of their network.

However, if I execute `service network restart` or indeed `systemctl restart network.service`, the VPN interface does not come up, nor does the IP route get added. If I manually execute `ifdown eth0`, and then `ifup eth0`, it also does not run the script as intended.

If I execute `/sbin/ifup-local eth0` the script runs as expected, so I know my script is fine, and I know my `ifup-local` is fine.

Am I missing something obvious? I've never worked with pre/post up scripts before, but I always figured they were pretty simple. Was I wrong?

Comment: Did you check the `ifup-post` script (in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`)? Is your `ifup-local` script called from there?

Comment: Hi Leon, YEs I should have mentioned, sorry. "idup-post" has the following called towards the bottom of the file:

`if [ -x /sbin/ifup-local ]; then
    /sbin/ifup-local ${DEVICE}`

Comment: Add `set -x; exec &> /tmp/ifup-post.log` to the beginning of the `ifup-post` script. Then run `ifdown eth0; ifup eth0` and check the contents of `/tmp/ifup-post.log`. If it is empty, then the ifup-post script was simply not called. Otherwise it should contain a trace of what goes wrong in `ifup-post`.

Answer (score 7):

Ensure your `ifcfg-eth0` script includes

```
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

Otherwise, calling `systemctl restart network` or `ifup eth0` will not execute `ifup-pre-local`, `ifup-eth`, `ifup-post`, `ifup-local`, etc. for `eth0`. They will still be called for `lo`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it might help anyone, to let the `ifup-local` script be called, execute the following commands:

```bash
chmod +x /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-local
ln -s /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-local /sbin/ifup-local
```

### Using Network Manager

As the *network-scripts* are deprecated, one might consider configuring a hook for *NetworkManager* in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`. For example:

```bash
touch    /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/eth0-listener.sh
chmod +x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/eth0-listener.sh
```

Then put something like the following inside `eth0-listener.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

interface=$1
event=$2


if [[ ${interface} != "eth0" ]] || [[ ${event} != "up" ]]
then
  # Nothing to do. We are not interested in the event nor the interface. 
  exit 0
fi


# Your initialisation commands go here:
# For example:
# ip route add x.x.x.x/y via z.z.x.x
```